# Windows Mouse - Soft Mouse if Hardware is removed or faulty?

Tags: c#, mouse

I have a remote system that uses Mouse and Keyboard to action events, mostly email data.

Now and again, I loose the mouse - User Unplug

My Application is programmed in C#.

I have looked at Legacy Mouse Drivers, but windows 10 does not seem to support this old tech any more.

How can I fool windows into thinking there is a Mouse still connected and working? Or is there a work around for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MickyD's answer was excellent, but it wasn't quite there. I had to trick Windows into seeing a mouse movement with:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint cButtons, uint dwExtraInfo);

private const uint MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE = 0x8000;
private const uint MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = 0x0001;

uint dest_x = (uint)(coordinate.X * 65535 / System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width);
uint dest_y = (uint)(coordinate.Y * 65535 / System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);

mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE + MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, dest_x, dest_y, 0, 0);
```

Note  This function has been superseded. Use SendInput instead.

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260(v=vs.85).aspx

So far this is working, even after a re-boot!

I hope this helps others out there!

Answer (score 2):

*"Fooling"* the mouse would probably need to be done from the OS-level rather than from an app.  Luckily there is a way with **no programming required**.

Windows 10 (and perhaps prior versions of Windows) has a setting in *Control Panel* called *Ease of Access mouse settings*.  On this page you will find a setting titled **Use numeric keypad to move mouse around the screen**, that when enabled does exactly what it says.

[image]

Windows applications are totally oblivious that mouse-overs and clicks are actually being instigated by the keyboard and not a regular mouse.

Comment: This worked until a reboot. After Reboot, no mouse pointer/Cursor - Sorry, I had to un-mark as answer as its not the complete solution although an excellent one - Thank You!

Comment: @RustyNail so just re-enable it after re-boot.  Job done

Comment: Only way to do that is by plugging in the Mouse again, it does not work other wise. No mouse, no Pointer/Cursor, no moving the mouse around the screen.

Comment: @RustyNail Incorrect.  Ease of access does not require mouse.  It is the whole point

Comment: Perhaps a Windows Bug, I have tested for many hours, and as soon as Mouse is unplugged and PC is rebooted, it stops working. It does work up until the Reboot. Microsoft, any ideas?